# Add CountDown to every json object in Node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, countdown

I have problem that : Before pushing the "complaint" in "Array" , "deadline" should have deadline = 7Days-24Hours-60Minutes and it should deacrese as day passes.

I have Array of json objects

```
var Array = [
    { 
    category   :  'a'
    firstName  :  'jack',
    lastName   :  'jack',
    deadline   :  ?
    }
{ 
    category   :  'b'
    firstName  :  'xyz',
    lastName   :  'pqr',
    deadline   :  ?
    }
];
```

Im taking these values form route

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res){

    complaint = {
        category: req.body.complainCategory,
        firstName: req.body.FirstName,
        lastName: req.body.LastName,
        deadLine: "?"
    };

    Array.push(complaint);

    res.redirect("/");
});
```

And then Displaying full "Array" on the other route.
I have problem that : Before pushing the "complaint" in "Array" , "deadline" should have deadline = 7Days-24Hours-60Minutes and it should deacrese as day passes.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have problem that : Before pushing the "complaint" in "Array" , "deadline" should have value deadline = 7Days-24Hours-60Minutes and it should deacrese as day passes.

Comment: You want the data to change automatically after you sent it?

Comment: no, I won't set the value "deadline" as equal to "7day" after that push "complaint" to "Array", but as time goes the value of "deadline" should decrease and at last "deadline" must equal to 0day.

Comment: yes, I want the data to change automatically after I sent it.

Comment: @FidaKhan Please take a piece of paper, and write a number on it with a permanent pen. Now, tell me, how do you make the number of the piece of paper count down?

Comment: I know but, please understand it properly, I don't know how to do it and Im new to javascript and nodejs, I want that whenever an object added to array it should bind to a countdown or present date, the value of deadline is not static it should be dynamic, you can take example of alarm application, whenever we add new alarm it is added to list of alarms and every alarm has its own time or countdown.

Comment: You save the date and time of the deadline. When you process the data in the object you take the deadline and subtract that from the current time. Now you have the difference.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to save the actual date with 7 days in advance and save it to the "deadline" and when you try to check the deadline just compare it to the actual date

```
var date_actual = new Date();
var deadline = new Date(date_actual.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
complaint = {
        category: req.body.complainCategory,
        firstName: req.body.FirstName,
        lastName: req.body.LastName,
        deadLine: deadline
    };
```

Comment: thanks, but the format of date is so hard, how can I get a date in this format (20-Mar-2020)